# how to use tailwindcss with gulp?

Tags: gulp, tailwind-css, postcss

i tryed use tailwindcss with gulp,this is my `gulpfile.js` file，but it didn't work...

```js
const gulp = require('gulp')
const browserSync = require('browser-sync')
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss')
const less = require('gulp-less')
const px2rem = require('postcss-px2rem')
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer')
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano')
const rename = require('gulp-rename')
const precss = require('precss')
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss')

gulp.task('cssMobile', function() {
  const plugins = [
    px2rem({ remUnit: 75 }),
    precss,
    tailwindcss,
  ]
  return gulp.src(cssMobileCompilePath)
             .pipe(less())
             .pipe(postcss(plugins, {}))
             .pipe(cssnano())
             .pipe(autoprefixer())
             .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
             .pipe(gulp.dest(`${basePath}/mobile`))
             .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
})
```

and i tryed put this code in my *.less root.

```less
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

when i was run gulp, tailwindcss is didn't packed in my css files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can reference [gulp-with-tailwindcss](https://github.com/lazymozek/gulp-with-tailwindcss)

Comment: Thanks for tagging the repo. I have updated the repo to latest version :)

Answer (score 0):

Greeting!

First you need to create tailwind config. in terminal:

```
npx tailwindcss init
```

it will create **tailwind.config.cjs**

Next you need to assign tailwind.config.cjs for tailwind plugin by passing it in argument.
In your case:

```
const plugins = [
    px2rem({ remUnit: 75 }),
    precss,
    tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.cjs'),
  ]
```

Here I assume your gulpfile.js and tailwind.config.cjs are in the same folder

Next in tailwind.config.cjs point files whitch tailwind must watch like below:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
      './src/**/*.html',
      './src/**/*.js',
      './src/**/*.scss',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I guess I don't need to explain how you need to specify path

Then if you use livereload like a browsersync you need to set in gulp.watch your cssMobile task also for html and js if you want to see applying tailwind classes wherever just in time.
example:

```
function watcher() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, scss);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, scss);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, scss);
}
```

**Note**
You don't need use gulp-autoprefixer before tailwind.
You need use pure autoprefixer by

```
npm i -D autoprefixer
```

Then

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
```

And then pass it to postcss plugins after tailwind:

```
const plugins = [
    px2rem({ remUnit: 75 }),
    precss,
    tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.cjs'),
    autoprefixer,
  ]
```

And finaly for perfect autoprefixer work you can add **.browserslistrc** file. I'm using the same

```
> 1%
ie >= 8
edge >= 15
ie_mob >= 10
ff >= 45
chrome >= 45
safari >= 7
opera >= 23
ios >= 7
android >= 4
bb >= 10
```

Or rather then in **package.json** specify:

```
"browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "ie >= 8",
    "edge >= 15",
    "ie_mob >= 10",
    "ff >= 45",
    "chrome >= 45",
    "safari >= 7",
    "opera >= 23",
    "ios >= 7",
    "android >= 4",
    "bb >= 10"
  ],
```

I hope it was helpful